# Get dependencies of R downloaded (but not installed) library

Tags: r, package

## TL;DR

Assume a folder which contains the source ( `*.tar.gz`) archives of R libraries with **all** the needed dependencies. How do I determine the order in which I should install these packages, knowing that dpendencies must be installed before their respective dependent library?

---

### Use Case

I have a remote machine with no access to the internet. Thus, I have to download libraries manually on my office machine, transfer them to the remote machine and install them there locally.

### Current Solution

Following the advice from [Install packages in R without internet connection with all dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929114/install-packages-in-r-without-internet-connection-with-all-dependencies) I get a list of all recursive dependencies of the the package I want to install, download them (as source) to a network drive and can eventually install them from there.

```
getDependencies <- function(packs){
   dependencyNames <- unlist(
      tools::package_dependencies(packages = packs, db = available.packages(), 
                                  which = c("Depends", "Imports"),
                                  recursive = TRUE))
   packageNames <- union(packs, dependencyNames)
   packageNames
}
# Calculate dependencies
packages <- getDependencies(c("tidyverse", "data.table"))
download.packages(pkgs = packages, destdir = getwd(), type = "source")
```

### Problem

With all the `*.tar.gz` files being properly downloaded to the network drive, I could theoretically loop through all files in this transfer directory and install them one by one. The problem, of course, lies in the dependencies, because package `A` may rely on package `B`, hence, package `B` should be installed prior to package `B`.

I *could* save `packages` in a `csv` (actually that's what the original post does), and read in this file in reverse order (assuming that `package_dependencies` lists dependencies after the dependent packages) and install the packages in this order.

I was now wondering, though, if I could achieve the same thing *without* the workaround of saving the list simply by using the downloaded packages themselves? Bea in mind that on the remote machine, I have no connection to the internet, so any solution must work purely with the information at hand. That is the `*.tar.gz` files and any other information obtainable from plain `R`.